# protobuf-net: Deserializing onto an instance; setting property to null

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net's serialization library and my team came across an interesting use case. In our application, we're deserializing a byte array onto an existing instance. The existing instance has properties, some are nullable and some aren't. The issue that I'm facing is that if a nullable property on the existing instance has a value, but the serialized instance just received over the wire doesn't have a value for that property. Since Protocol Buffers doesn't have a concept of null, null isn't serialized into the byte array and thus the deserialize call doesn't overwrite the nullable property with null.

In case you couldn't follow that, I wrote a quick unit test to illustrate my point/question:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class WhenSerializingNullableProperties 
    {
        private RuntimeTypeModel _runtimeTypeModel;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void FixtureSetup()
        {
            _runtimeTypeModel = TypeModel.Create();
            _runtimeTypeModel.Add(typeof (Foo), false).Add("Id", "Name");
        }

        internal class Foo 
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int? Id { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldSetNullablePropertiesToNull()
        {
            var foo = new Foo { Name = "name", Id = null };

            byte[] serialized;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                _runtimeTypeModel.Serialize(stream, security);
                serialized = stream.ToArray();
            }

            foo.Id = 18;
            foo.Name = "other";

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(serialized))
            {
                _runtimeTypeModel.Deserialize(stream, foo, typeof(Foo));
            }

            foo.Name.Should().Be("name"); // this PASSES
            foo.Id.Should().NotHaveValue(); // this FAILS
        }
    }
```

I understand (and am grateful for) protobuf's compactness with excluding nulls. I don't want to throw in a default value and have my streams be larger. Instead, I'm looking for protobuf-net to set a nullable property to null if it's not included in the stream being deserialized.

Thanks in advance for any and all help provided.